# How to read .m file as NSString in iOS

Tags: ios, nsbundle

I am trying to display an implementation file(Code inside the .m file) in UITextView. Below is the code snippet i used. But it returns nil.

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"TextCheck.m" ofType:@"m"];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"TextCheck.m" ofType:@"m"];
```

Replace the code as below line :

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"TextCheck" ofType:@"m"];
```

Answer (score 1):

I really doubt you can do this.  The source code is not a 'resource'..When you execute the app they are in binary form.. there is no code in there..

If you need to do display something that you know already - try storing the text/code you intend to display in a plain file and display..